# Facebook-like messaging system with image upload

Tags: facebook, image, upload, system, messaging

I am designing a facebook-like messaging system but have problems with image uploads within the message. text input.

How do i go about it. Do i use input or `div`?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```